# Mapping values from small dataframe to larger dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes.
DF1:

```
Page      LineNum      Value
1          1            0.5
1          2            0.6
1          3            0.7
2          1            0.9
2          2            0.4
```

DF2: **The initial dataframe is of first three columns and I have to generate the fourth column named New_Value.**

```
Page      LineNum      Word    New_Value
1          1            g1      0.5
1          1            g2      0.5
1          1            g3      0.5
1          1            g4      0.5
1          2            g5      0.6
1          2            g6      0.6
1          3            g7      0.7
1          3            g8      0.7
...
```

I have to generate the fourth column of DF2 which is actually mapped from DF1's unique 'Page' and 'LineNum' values. In DF2 the values are just repeated according to the unique values in DF1 with respect to "Page" and "LineNum".

I am currently doing this by a for loop:

```
    for index, row in DF1.iterrows():
        DF2.ix[((DF2['Page'] == row['Page']) & (DF2['LineNum'] == row['LineNum'])),['New_Value']] = row['Value']
```

This works absolutely fine but there both dataframes are very large. So I need some optimized function perhaps using groupby and lambda but couldn't devise exact function.

Please suggest an optimized version without For loop.
please comment if there is something else I need to explain about this.
I am using Python3 and pandas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think need [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with left join:

```
df = (df2.merge(df1.rename(columns={'Value':'New_Value'}),
                on=['Page','LineNum'], how='left'))
print (df)

   Page  LineNum Word  New_Value
0     1        1   g1        0.5
1     1        1   g2        0.5
2     1        1   g3        0.5
3     1        1   g4        0.5
4     1        2   g5        0.6
5     1        2   g6        0.6
6     1        3   g7        0.7
7     1        3   g8        0.7
```